# ¿Por qué no salta ninguna excepción cuando está mal escrita la cadena de conexión en la llamada al constructor de la clase PDO?

Tags: php

Por ejemplo, si tengo este código en PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>conexion_PDO_I.php</title>
  <link href="./css/dwes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $usuario = 'dwes';
    $contrasenia = 'dwes';

    try
    {
        // Se pueden usar tanto comillas simples como dobles
        $base = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dwes', $usuario, $contrasenia);
        echo "Conexión realizada";
    }catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Error " . $e->getMessage ();
        die ();
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto está bien escrito y no salta excepción alguna. Pero me he equivocado y he puesto "dbMame" en vez de "dbname" y no ha saltado la excepción. He provocado varios fallos adrede, para ver cuándo saltaba la excepción y cuándo no, y sólo salta cuando:

- Se pone mal el nombre del driver para mysql
- Se pone mal el nombre del servidor
- Se pone mal el nombre de la base de datos
- Se pone mal el usuario
- Se pone mal la contraseña

No sé si ésto sea un bug del constructor, o si me falte pasar algún parámetro más de los que son opcionales, pero no controla un error en los literales "host" y "dbname" en la cadena de conexión que el constructor recibe como primer parámetro.

¿Hay alguna manera de obligar a PHP para que controle estos errores?

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué este editor recorta el código como le da la gana?. Mi comentario era más largo y ha borrado casi todo. Y si pregunto por ser novata me dan malas puntuaciones y me borran los comentarios. Y si doy las gracias por que me ayuden también

Comment: Carmen, bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Un poco de paciencia al principio, verás que es muy simple el uso de este sitio. En cuanto a tu pregunta, si atribuyes el modo error a la conexión, te va a capturar los demás errores. Puedes hacerlo colocando en el `try`, después de `new $base...`, el siguiente atributo : **`$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`** Para más detalles [puedes ver el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php) donde se explican los diferentes modos de notificación de errores para PDO. Si no estableces nada el modo por defecto ...

Comment: ... es `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`, por lo que en tu caso, es probable que se esté saltando notificar algunos errores. Está todo explicado en el enlace. Si te decides a usar PDO, tienes que setear bien la configuración de emulación de consultas, es un paso importante de cara a evitar la inyección de código, pero te hablaré de eso en otro momento. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer php no hace ninguna validación en los parámetros del DSN y solo ocupa los que estén bien escritos. por eso no lanza ninguna excepción por que se conecta a mysql pero no a una base de datos en concreto.

```
<?php
try
{
    // Se pueden usar tanto comillas simples como dobles
    $base = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbXame=dwes;charset=utf8;cualquiercosa=estonolanzaexcepcion', $usuario, $contrasenia);        
    echo "Conexión realizada";//aca estas conectado a mysql
    var_dump($base->query('SHOW DATABASES')->fetchAll());//con esto muestras todas las base de datos que tienes acceso.
    $base->exec('USE dwes');//aca te conectas a la base de datos "dwes"
}catch (PDOException $e)
{
    print "Error " . $e->getMessage ();
    die ();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Es normal que no se genere una excepción ya que el campo `dbname` de la [DSN de conexión](http://php.net/pdo-mysql.connection) no es obligatorio, no es necesariamente un error:

```
<?php
try {
    // Se pueden usar tanto comillas simples como dobles
    $base = new PDO (
      'mysql:host=localhost',
      $usuario,
      $contrasenia
    );
    echo "<p>Conexión realizada</p>";
    $consulta = $base->query('SELECT * FROM dwes.pruebas');
    if ($consulta !== false) {
        echo "<p>Consulta hecha</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Consulta fallida: ",
          htmlspecialchars($base->errorInfo()[2]),
          "</p>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}
```

Como puedes ver se puede realizar una conexión a un servidor de bases de datos MySQL sin seleccionar una base de datos y posteriormente hacer una consulta en la que se indica de manera explícita la base de datos a la que pertenece la tabla.

Además, para evitar problemas cuando se incluyen nuevos parámetros a la cadena DSN de conexión MySQL (todo aquello que se escribe tras el carácter `;`) se ignoran silenciosamente aquellos que no se reconozcan. Esto permite, por ejemplo, que la conexión no falle cuando se use `charset` antes de PHP 5.3.6 (versión en la que fue incorporado este parámetro).

Si la tabla `dwes.pruebas` (`pruebas` dentro de la base de datos `dwes`) no existe aparecerá el mensaje de error:

```
Consulta fallida: Table 'dwes.pruebas' doesn't exist
```

Podrías cambiar de base de datos en cualquier momento haciendo uso de la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
USE <base de datos>
```

Answer (score 0):

Carmen lo que puedes hacer es gestionar los errores por cuenta propia. Luego de ejecutar tu consulta averigua al `$base->errorInfo()` por cualquier error generado, por ejemplo que la base de datos no fue seleccionada.

Answer (score 0):

### I. La causa

**Al no establecer ningún modo de manejo de errores cuando creas el objeto conexión, éste adquiere el modo por defecto para PDO que es `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`.**

Si revisamos el [código fuente de PDO](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h#L186), podemos ver lo siguiente:

```
#define PDO_ERR_NONE                "00000"

enum pdo_error_mode {
    PDO_ERRMODE_SILENT,     /* just set error codes */
    PDO_ERRMODE_WARNING,    /* raise E_WARNING */
    PDO_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION   /* throw exceptions */
};
```

Los comentarios a la derecha explican en resumen lo que haría cada estado de reporte de errores. En el modo silencioso dice, *just set error codes*. O sea, que setea los código de errores, pero no reporta nada.

Dicho en otras palabras, en este modo ciertos errores no son reportados, como ocurre en tu caso y por eso no puedes capturarlos en el bloque `try`. En la parte `III` veremos una forma de reportarlos.

El manual documenta de forma más extensa lo que hemos visto más arriba en el código fuente.

`PDO` ofrece tres estrategias diferentes de manejar errores para adaptarse a cualquier estilo de desarrollo de aplicaciones.

- `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`
- `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`
- `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

El Manual dice que **el modo predeterminado es `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`**. Cuando este modo está establecido, ocurre lo siguiente:

> PDO simplemente establecerá él mismo el código de error para su
>   inspección utilizando los métodos [`PDO::errorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorcode.php) y
>   [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php) tanto en objetos de sentencias como de bases
>   de datos. Si el error resultó de una llamada a un objeto de sentencia,
>   se deberá invocar al método [`PDOStatement::errorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorcode.php) o
>   [`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) sobre dicho objeto. Si el error
>   resultó de una llamada a un objeto de bases de datos, se deberá
>   invocar, en su lugar, a los métodos del objeto de bases de datos.
>
> <sub>❯ Fuente: [Errores y su manejo en el Manual de
>   PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php)</sub>

---

### II. ¿Omitir `dbname` es un error?

Al menos en MySQL sí lo es. Es el `Error: 1046`, como se puede ver en en apartado [B.3 Server Error Codes and Messages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_no_db_error) de la documentación.

Es efectivamente un error que se puede capturar, como veremos en el siguiente punto.

---

### III. ¿Qué hacer?

No se recomienda, al menos en la etapa de desarrollo, tener el reporte de errores en silencio.

Para cambiar esto PDO cuenta con el método [`setAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.setattribute.php), a través del cual se puede pasar uno o más atributos para terminar de configurar nuestro objeto conexión.

Si tú, después de crear el objeto de conexión activas el reporte de errores mediante este método, podrás ver que sí se captura la excepción.

Hagamos una prueba y de paso vemos con código cómo se usa el método:

```
/*Escribimos mal dbname a propósito*/
$dsn="mysql:host=localhost;fakedbname=xfiddlec_max;port=3306";
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch (PDOException $e){
    print "Error " . $e->getMessage();
    die ();
}
```

En este código la excepción es capturada, y podrás ver este mensaje en pantalla:

> Exception: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database
>   selected

Además, la ventaja de hacer esto al crear el objeto conexión, es que no tendrás que encerrar en bloques `try ... catch` ninguno de los futuros usos relativos a la conexión. Simplemente, evaluar tus variables adecuadamente y controlar el todo momento el flujo de tu programa.

---

### IV. Otro uso muy importante de `setAttribute`

Ya que estás iniciando con PDO, me permitiré señalarte algo que también es muy importante de cara a la seguridad.

Cuando creas tu objeto conexión, además de setear el atributo anterior, debes setear imperativamente un atributo llamado `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` a `FALSE`. Esto es debido a que su estado por defecto es `TRUE`, y cuando este modo está establecido, el objeto conexión permite la emulación de consultas preparadas, lo cual podría inducir a la Inyección SQL en determinados casos. (No quiero abundar más en esto porque no es el tema de esta pregunta, pero si te interesa, puedes leer más sobre esto en la pregunta dedicada específicamente al tema de la Inyección SQL).

Puedes usar `setAttribute` también para establecer el conjunto de caracteres que deberá usar el objeto conexión. Conviene que sea `UTF-8`, así quitas la posibilidad de que los datos como acentos, `ñ` y otros, se muestren como caracteres extraños en algunos escenarios.

Para terminar, dejo un ejemplo de conexión estableciendo los atributos antes mencionados:

```
/*Cuando se pasan varios atributos es mejor pasarlos juntos en un array*/
$arrOpciones = array(
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
                        );
try {
        $pdo= new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $arrOpciones);

    }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error " . $e->getMessage ();
    }
```

Eso es todo.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.